# Router not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Can someone tell me why the navigation is not working? When I click on the button nothing happened but work. But if I use
`<router-outlet></router-outlet>` it works.

This is my my app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SettingsComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule,

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [LoginComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
    firebase.initializeApp({

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: need component and template code to answer your code.Ans what do you mean by But if I use <router-outlet></router-outlet> it works.

Comment: when i use <router-outlet></router-outlet> we can see the other component page inside the current page.But if I want to navigate to the other page it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is my my app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/register', pathMatch: 'full' }
]
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{ enableTracing: true })
  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

template code

```
</div><a id="login"  [routerLink]="['dashboard']"  class="btn btn-primary">Login</a>
```

Comment: is this the answer ...??